# Parse Controller variable to javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller with a show action. I have a date variable @year = @order.ordered.year

I want to pass this value to javascript that I have in my application.js file so I can output it in the view because I have a javascript time counter on the page and need to parse the values to it. I thought I could add the following to the js file but it doesn't work. How should I do this?

var year = <% @year.to_json %>;

Answer (score 0):

just a guess, but have you tried using `<%= %>` brackets instead, that actually yields something whereas the other just does ruby code

Comment: Yes I did try this but it doesn't work. Can I add this directly to my application.js file?